# How to scrape a url containing # using python scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, fragment-identifier

I am using python scrapy to scrape a website.
The webpage is of the form http://www.cuponation.in/myntra-coupons#voucher-13537
it contains '#' in it. While scraping this webpage as start_url it ignores the part after #.

Is there a way i can scrape the fullurl with # in it using python scrapy

Comment: `#` is just going to take you to a particular place on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While scraping it's usual that it ignores the part after `#`. The symbol usually takes you to a `<div>` tag on the webpage that has an `id` equal to 'voucher-13537', that's all it means. So once you scrape the page, you should try to look for something similar to:

```
<div id="voucher-13537">
```

and that is what you'd be looking for.

Talking about parsing html files, if you don't already use it, I would suggest you look into `BeautifulSoup4` module.

Comment: +1 for mentioning BeautifulSoup4 which might be more appropriate for the OP